# AWS AppSync - Error during subscription handshake

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, graphql, apollo, aws-appsync

When I have not resolver for subscription I dont have any problem with subscription but when I set the resolver to allow only specific users, in my angular App I have this error

> appsync.service.ts:187 Error: Error during subscription handshake
>       at new ApolloError (ApolloError.js:37)
>       at subscription-handshake-link.js:116
>       at new Subscription (Observable.js:183)
>       at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:262)
>       at index.js:20
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:388)
>       at Object.onInvoke (core.js:3820)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:387)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
>       at zone.js:872

**Resolver**

**Data source type**: NONE

**Configure the request mapping template.**

```
#set ($a= $context.identity.cognitoIdentityAuthProvider.split(":"))
#set ($s= $a.get(2))
#set ($stringLength = $s.length() - 1) 
#set ($sub = $s.substring(0,$stringLength))


{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "payload": {
        "from": "$sub",
        "id":"${context.arguments.id}"
    }
}
```

**Configure the response mapping template.**

```
#if(${context.arguments.id} == ${context.result.from})
    $util.toJson($context.result)
#else
    $utils.unauthorized()
#end
```

Only for simplify, I tried this resolver response but I had same error

```
$util.toJson($context.result)
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? Schema, Types, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remplace **$util.toJson($context.result)** for **null** work fine.

```
#if(${context.arguments.id} == ${context.result.from})
    null
#else
    $utils.unauthorized()
#end
```